# How do I add multiple cellvalue in a IF function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript

I'm trying to add more values with "Select a name" to the script so when any of these values pop up it'll clearcontent

```
function onEdit(e) {
  
  let range=e.range;
  let activeRow = range.getRow();
  let activeColumn = range.getColumn();
  let cellValue = range.getValue();
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();


    if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == 'PUBG Videos') {
    if (activeColumn == 26) {

      if (cellValue == "Select a name") {

          sheet.getRange(activeRow,25).clearContent();

      }

      else {

          sheet.getRange(activeRow,25).setValue(new Date());

      }
      }



    if (activeColumn == 31) {

      if (cellValue == false) {

          sheet.getRange(activeRow,32).clearContent();

      } else {

          sheet.getRange(activeRow,32).setValue(new Date());

      }

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `&&` you can add conditions to be met together and with `||` you can set conditions that will pass when at least one is met